# Nginx reverse proxy Docker

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a reverse proxy in a docker container.

The nginx.conf look like this :

```
 upstream app1 {
     server app1:8080;
   }


  server {

      location /app1 {
          proxy_pass http://app1;
          include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
      }

 }
```

The Dockerfile look like this :

```
  FROM nginx
  COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
```

after the build I run the nginx container like this :

```
docker run --publish=80:80 --link app1:app1 nginx
```

And I get an error when I try acces myWebSite/app1 in my browser

Where is my mistake ?

**UPDATE**

the log error:

```
2017/07/19 05:39:37 [error] 6#6: *1 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/app1" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: myComputerIp, server: localhost, request: "GET /app1 HTTP/1.1", host: "myWebSite"
```

**UPDATE 2**

I try :

```
docker exec -it <id_container> curl app1
```

But curl is not install in container and when try to install it (with the Dockerfile), apt-get don't found package.

Any Idea ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you update this post with your docker logs to know what is error, exactly?

Comment: I assumre `appl1` is a container? You'll have to make sure that is visible to your nginx container as well. You might want to try pinging `app1` inside the nginx container

Comment: @Dalton Any idea ?

Comment: Your config has port 8080, but you are running the container binding 80:80... Have your tried to change this?